# Copy paste range using "for....next" with step

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy a range between sheets using for..next with step, but I'm not fluent with using the for..next statement. I have recorded the step with macro, here is the code:

```
Sub Macro1()
   Range("A2:A22").Select
   Selection.Copy
   Sheets("Sheet4").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Sheets("db_pivot").Select
   Range("C2:C22").Select
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Selection.Copy
   Sheets("Sheet4").Select
   Range("B2").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Sheets("db_pivot").Select
   Range("E2:E22").Select
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Selection.Copy
   Sheets("Sheet4").Select
   Range("C2").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Sheets("db_pivot").Select
   Range("G2:G22").Select
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Selection.Copy
   Sheets("Sheet4").Select
   Range("D2").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Could you convert the code with for..next statement with step?

Comment: You should attempt to convert the recorded macro to the form that you want and then come here with any specific problems that you cannot solve yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Uninon` to group your non-continous Columns in one Range.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim DBPivotSht As Worksheet
Dim Sht4 As Worksheet
Dim UnionRng As Range

' get used to allways define your worksheet objects
Set DBPivotSht = Worksheets("db_pivot")
Set Sht4 = Worksheets("Sheet4")

With DBPivotSht
    Set UnionRng = Union(.Range("A2:A22"), .Range("C2:C22"), .Range("E2:E22"), .Range("G2:G22"))
End With

' copy the entire Union range and paste in "Sheet4"
UnionRng.Copy Destination:=Sht4.Range("A2")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Without FOR ... NEXT statement, I propose this code

```
With Sheets("db_pivot")
    .Range("A2:A22").Copy Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1")
    .Range("C2:C22").Copy Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B2")
    .Range("E2:E22").Copy Sheets("Sheet4").Range("C2")
    .Range("G2:G22").Copy Sheets("Sheet4").Range("D2")
End With
```

HTH
Jon

Comment: Thank you @Jon, your solution is working. I have tested the code but, I think using Union more efficient especially times for running.